# Writing an equivalent of Python's input function in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a simple equivalent of Python's `input` function in Bash.

An example in a Python script would be something like this:

```
s = input('Please input something: ')
```

I imagine the call to a Bash equivalent would look like this:

```
s=$(input "Please input something: ")
```

This is the implementation that I wrote:

```
function input {
    # $1 is the prompt passed as an argument; in my above example,
    # it would be 'Please input something: '
    printf "%s" "$1"
    read in
    echo "${in}"
    return 0
}
```

With the call `s=$(input "Please enter something: ")`, the prompt never prints; instead, the Bash script simply waits for user input without ever displaying the text. Pressing Enter, that is, giving no input, sets `s` to the prompt itself. What seems to be happening is `s` captures the output from the line `printf "%s" "$1"`, then reads input which it also echoed back. I have also tried explicitly directing the prompt to `stdout` with `printf "%s" "$1" >&1`, but to no avail.

How can I print the prompt first, then capture input and echo it back to the calling function?

Comment: JohnK's answer is the right one, but that said -- to make your prompt go to the TTY without getting captured, write it to stderr, not stdout -- which also has the fortunate benefit of being unbuffered by default, whereas when stdout is directed to a TTY it's line-buffered by default. Incidentally, the shell's own prompts go to stderr as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck. It already exists in the form of `read -p`.

```
read -p 'Please input something: ' s
```

To be safe, it's a good idea to use `IFS=` and `-r` as well. `IFS=` makes sure leading and trailing whitespace are retained. `-r` preserves backslashes so `\n` isn't interpreted as a newline, or `\\` turned into `\`.

```
IFS= read -rp 'Please input something: ' s
```

As to why your function doesn't work, it's because the prompt is being printed to stdout, which is captured. Print to stderr to get it to show up.

```
input() {
    printf "%s" "$1" >&2
    read in
    printf '%s\n' "$in"
}
```

A careful scripter will use `printf '%s\n'` in place of `echo`. If the user types `-n` or `-e` you want those printed, not interpreted as options.